# Deleting a Node and all of its relations in Neo4j

Tags: java, spring, neo4j, spring-data, spring-data-neo4j

I am trying to delete all `Type`'s from my Neo4j database.  I have a repository for the `Type` class, `typeRepository`, which I call `typeRepository.deleteAll();`.  However, not everything is deleted.  Only its node is deleted leaving the `BusinessLogic` node alive in the database.  I am not sure what else to try at this point, since it name of the method implies that it will delete all things including itself and things related to itself.  Here is how my persisted class looks, which extends a base type of object that my database contains:

```
@NodeEntity
public class BaseType {

    @GraphId
    private Long id;

    @Indexed(unique=true) String uid;
    private String name;

    BaseType() {}

    BaseType(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }
}
```

,

```
public class Type extends BaseType {

    @RelatedTo(type="businessLogic")
    @Fetch
    private BusinessLogic businessLogic;

    public Type() {super();}

    public Type(String name, BusinessLogic businessLogic) {
        super(name);
        this.businessLogic = businessLogic;
    }
}
```

,

```
@NodeEntity
@XmlAccessorType(XmlAccessType.NONE)
public class BusinessLogic implements Serializable {

    @GraphId
    private Long id;

    private static final long serialVersionUID = -634875134095817304L;

    @XmlElement
    private String create;

    public void setCreate(String create) {
        this.create = create;
    }

    public String getCreate() {
        return create;
    }
}
```

I only store the `Type` instances, and I do that by calling

`typeRepository.save(new Type(name, businessLogic));`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't think SDN is doing cascading delete on its own. So, why don't you first delete the BusinessLogic objects via their respective repository, and then the Type objects?

Comment: I do not have a BusinessLogic repository.

Comment: just do it somewhere outside the domain classes, like in a service, controller or repository object and inject the Neo4jTemplate for the operations.